# Get output column for each Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database with roughly this fields:

```
SELECT [UserId]
  ,[MissionId]
  ,[LevelId]
  ,[Key]
  ,[BooleanAnswer]
  ,[CreationDateTimeUtc]
  ,[QuestionId]
  FROM [Bakman].[dbo].[LevelEntries]
  WHERE LevelId = 2 AND QuestionId = 1 OR QuestionId = 2 OR QuestionId = 3 OR QuestionId = 4 OR QuestionId = 5 OR QuestionId = 6
```

Now I get this kind of output:

```
UserId  MissionId   LevelId Key BooleanAnswer   CreationDateTimeUtc QuestionId
0      1            2       1   1               2017-10-07 11:39:26.350 1
0      1            2       2   1               2017-10-07 11:39:26.350 1
0      1            2       3   0               2017-10-07 11:39:26.350 1
0      1            2       4   1               2017-10-07 11:39:26.350 1
0      1            2       5   0               2017-10-07 11:39:26.350 1
0      1            2       6   1               2017-10-07 11:39:26.350 1
```

But now I want to get a column for each QuestionId (which are equal to the [key]).

Like this :

```
       UserId   MissionId   LevelId Key1  Key2  Key3   Key4   Key5   Key6       CreationDateTimeUtc     QuestionId
      1         2       1     0     1     1     0      1      1      1          2017-10-07 11:39:26.350 1
```

Where Key[key] has the boolean awnser and the key belonging to that element.
Good to know is that the Userid + MissionId + LevelId + Key are the Composite key for this table.

EDIT:

Trying both given answers I now get something like this

```
    UserId  MissionId   LevelId Key1    Key2    Key3    Key4    Key5    Key6
   1    1   2   1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
    1   1   2   NULL    1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
    1   1   2   NULL    NULL    0   NULL    NULL    NULL    
    1   1   2   NULL    NULL    NULL    1   NULL    NULL    
    1   1   2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   NULL    
    1   1   2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1
```

Now I want to combine those so I get the level result of the user.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well, and perhaps also give us the sample table data.

Comment: Are you using Sybase or MS SQL Server?

Comment: MS SQL Server, I'll edit the question just a sec

Comment: @jarlh The Question is edited

Comment: Did you do randomly the expected result? It does not match with your data at all

Comment: @EdwardN As I tried to explain; There are several composite keys that are :  Userid + MissionId + LevelId + Key. 

Now you can give entries to questions, the questionId is the key in this case. I want that for each question in the level there will be a column with the given answer underneath (Where the answer is the BooleanAnswer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query

```
SELECT
  UserId,
  MissionId,
  LevelId,
  MAX(CASE WHEN [Key]=1 THEN BooleanAnswer END) Key1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN [Key]=2 THEN BooleanAnswer END) Key2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN [Key]=3 THEN BooleanAnswer END) Key3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN [Key]=4 THEN BooleanAnswer END) Key4,
  MAX(CASE WHEN [Key]=5 THEN BooleanAnswer END) Key5,
  MAX(CASE WHEN [Key]=6 THEN BooleanAnswer END) Key6,
  CreationDateTimeUtc,
  QuestionId
FROM LevelEntries
WHERE LevelId=2
  AND QuestionId IN(1,2,3,4,5,6)
GROUP BY UserId,MissionId,LevelId,CreationDateTimeUtc,QuestionId
```

The second variant

```
SELECT
  UserId,
  MissionId,
  LevelId,
  MAX(CASE WHEN [Key]=1 THEN BooleanAnswer END) Key1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN [Key]=2 THEN BooleanAnswer END) Key2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN [Key]=3 THEN BooleanAnswer END) Key3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN [Key]=4 THEN BooleanAnswer END) Key4,
  MAX(CASE WHEN [Key]=5 THEN BooleanAnswer END) Key5,
  MAX(CASE WHEN [Key]=6 THEN BooleanAnswer END) Key6,
  MAX(CreationDateTimeUtc) MaxCreationDateTimeUtc,
  QuestionId
FROM LevelEntries
WHERE LevelId=2
  AND QuestionId IN(1,2,3,4,5,6)
GROUP BY UserId,MissionId,LevelId,QuestionId
```

Comment: While that is a nicer way of doing the where clause in this case. It doesn't change the output format, that is mostly dictated by the select clause.
But thanks anyways!

Comment: I changed my answer.

Comment: *sorry my question

Comment: Try the second variant. I deleted CreationDateTimeUtc from GROUP BY and added avg function for this column MAX(CreationDateTimeUtc).

Comment: This fixed it! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PIVOT` for that purpose.

```
    with Entries as
    (
        select UserId,
            MissionId,
            LevelId,
            'Key' + cast([Key] as varchar) as [Key],
            BooleanAnswer,
            CreationDateTimeUtc,
            QuestionId
        from [Bakman].[dbo].[LevelEntries]
        where LevelId = 2 and QuestionId in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    )

    select UserId,
        MissionId,
        LevelId,
        Key1, 
        Key2, 
        Key3, 
        Key4, 
        Key5,
        Key6,
        CreationDateTimeUtc,
        QuestionId
    from Entries t
    pivot
    (
        max(BooleanAnswer)
        for [Key] in (Key1, Key2, Key3, Key4, Key5, Key6)
    ) p;
```

Comment: *sorry my question

Comment: I am sorry that I am not getting the issue in this query. I am getting the result in the desired format. Please check this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b34ce/1) and let me know if I am missing something.